# Column with Unique Index and Primary Key gives Unique Constraint Violation

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I just created a Table on PL/SQL Devloper. The Table I created has an ID column. For this column, I set up a primary key (PK_ID). The column also has a unique index with name PK_ID.

I tried to insert into this table by writing this:

```
INSERT INTO ADMIN.MESSAGE_LIST (TEXT, TEXTER, ID)
VALUES ('This is a Test','Tim', 1）;
```

And I get the error "ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADMIN.PK_ID) violated"

I have no other inserts in the table (it is currently empty) and I figured inserting 1 as the ID would be unique.

I also do not have a sequence and trigger set up to auto-increment the ID column, because I honestly do not know how to edit the table to do that (which is why I just inserted with the ID as 1 as a test).

Why can't I insert with an ID 1 if the table is empty? Wouldn't it still be unique in that case?

(Note: Running the command without including ID and the Value 1 gives me an error saying I cannot insert "NULL" into the ID column)

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that the table is empty.  You'd only get that error if there was another row in the table with an `ID` of 1.

Comment: Do you maybe have both a semicolon and a `/` on the next line, causing the statement to be executed twice? You'd see '1 row inserted' before the error message then. (Or two error messages trying to insert null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please execute a simple statement:

```
select * from admin.message_list where id = 1;
```

If it wouldn't return rows, you should check if constraint PK_ID refers to ID column and if so, ask Oracle support to fix a bug.